# Instead of returning a list i get nil as a return type

Tags: recursion, elixir

I am new to elixir and functional programming as whole. I was starting out with super basic functions until i found a problem I couldnt find on the internet.
I have the following module

```
defmodule Logic do
  def is_bigger_then_3(list_int, res) when length(list_int) > 0 do
    IO.inspect binding()
    [head | tail] = list_int
    if head > 3 do
      is_bigger_then_3 tail, res ++ [true]
    end
    unless head > 3 do
     is_bigger_then_3 tail, res ++ [false]
    end
  end
  def is_bigger_then_3(list_int, res) when length(list_int) == 0 do
    IO.inspect binding()
    res
  end
end
```

I am trying to make a list for every case a number is smaller or larger then 3.

my expected result is that eg: [1, 2, 3, 4] returns [false, false, false, true]
but for some reason the return value is nil.
This is what actually gets returned

```
iex(27)> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
iex(28)> Logic.is_bigger_then_3 list, []
[list_int: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], res: []]
[list_int: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], res: [false]]
[list_int: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], res: [false, false]]
[list_int: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], res: [false, false, false]]
[list_int: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], res: [false, false, false, true]]
[list_int: [6, 7, 8, 9], res: [false, false, false, true, true]]
[list_int: ~c"\a\b\t", res: [false, false, false, true, true, true]]
[list_int: ~c"\b\t", res: [false, false, false, true, true, true, true]]
[list_int: ~c"\t", res: [false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true]]
[list_int: [], res: [false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true]]
nil
```

I have absolutly no idea why I get nil as a result and I have no idea how this can be happening. An explanation would be very kind.

Comment: (Also consider `Enum.map(list, fn x -> x > 3 end)`: your output contains a matching value for each input in the same position, and `Enum.map/2` includes the core of looping over the list and producing the result.  Manually writing the recursive function is a good exercise, but it's probably easier to use the `Enum` module where possible.)

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate results are discarded unless stored in local vars and/or returned from the functions.

Here is your function with my comments.

```elixir
defmodule Logic do
  # we pattern-match here to ensure the length is > 0
  def is_bigger_then_3([head | tail] = list_int, res) do
    # calculated and then discarded
    if head > 3, do: is_bigger_then_3 tail, res ++ [true]
    # calculated and then returned as a function result
    unless head > 3, do: is_bigger_then_3 tail, res ++ [false]
  end

  def is_bigger_then_3([], res) do
    IO.inspect binding()
    res
  end
end
```

That said, instead of accumulating, you simply discard calculated values.

Somewhat alongside the below would work

```elixir
defmodule Logic do
  def is_bigger_then_3([head | tail] = list_int, res) do
    is_bigger_then_3 tail, res ++ [head > 3]
  end

  def is_bigger_then_3([], res), do: res
end
```

*Sidenote:* it’s more idiomatic to prepend to linked lists rather than append to them, as `[head > 3 | res]` instead of `res ++ [head > 3]` and then reverse the list. It was way more performant back then and still slightly more performant now.

Comment: Excellent point about prepending being more idiomatic than appending.

Answer (score 0):

> I have absolutly no idea why I get nil as a result

This is where the `nil` value originates from:

```
iex(9)> number = 9
9

iex(10)> unless number > 3 do
...(10)> IO.puts "hello"
...(10)> [1, 2, 3]
...(10)> end
nil
```

Note the absence of any "hello" output, which means the do block didn't execute, and note the return value of `nil`.

`if statements` and `unless statements` are *expressions*, which means they return values, and according to the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#unless/2):

> **unless(condition, clauses)**
>
> This macro evaluates ... the do block passed in as the second
> argument if condition evaluates to a falsy value (false or nil).
> **Otherwise, it returns the value of the else block if present or `nil` if not.**

If you trace what happens with the list `[1,9]`, you can see why your function returns nil:

```
f([1,9], []) do
   ...
   ...
   unless head > 3
      |---------------------> f([9], [false]) do 
   end                           if head > 3
end                                    |--------------> f([], [false, true] <==  2nd function clause executes and returns [false, true] to caller        
                                 end
                                 unless head > 3 
                                 end
                              end 

                                 |  |
                                 V  V

                              f([9], [false]) do 
                                if head > 3
                                   [false, true]  #After this is returned here, the unless below executes
                                end
                                unless head > 3  #The condition is true, so the do block does not execute, and the unless returns nil, which means this function call returns nil to the caller
                                end
                              end

                                  | |  Because if and unless are expressions, and expressions return values, 
                                  V V  this function call actually evaluates to:

                              f([9], [false]) do 
                                [false, true]
                                nil   #returns nil to caller
                              end
                               
                                 
f([1,9], [])
   ...
   ...
   unless head > 3 do
      nil     #After this is returned here, the do block evaluates to nil, so the unless returns nil, 
   end        #and because it's the last statement in the function, this function call returns nil
end
```

The lesson is: the recursive function call should be the
last line of your function.

Here's a video that shows you how to trace a recursive function using a pencil and paper (which is much easier than typing it out here):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUtEIJbn-k4

> my expected result is that eg: [1, 2, 3, 4] returns [false, false,
> false, true]

```
iex(2)> Enum.map([1,2,3,4], fn num -> num > 3 end) 
    [false, false, false, true]
```

Recursive functions that produce the same result:

```
defmodule MyFuncs do
  def elems_bigger_than(x, list), do: elems_bigger_than(x, list, [])

  def elems_bigger_than(x, [head|tail], results) do
    elems_bigger_than(x, tail, [ head > x | results])
  end
  def elems_bigger_than(_x, [], results), do: reverse(results)


  def reverse(list), do: reverse(list, [])
      
  def reverse([head|tail], results) do
    reverse(tail, [head | results])
  end
  def reverse([], results), do: results

end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs% iex b.ex
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.3.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1]
Interactive Elixir (1.14.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> MyFuncs.elems_bigger_than(3, [1, 2, 3, 4]) 
[false, false, false, true]

iex(2)> MyFuncs.elems_bigger_than(1, [1, 2, 3, 4])
[false, true, true, true]
```

The recursive functions above use what's known as the "accumulator trick".  First, you define a function that accepts the arguments the user will provide, then you immediately call another function with the user's arguments plus any arguments you will need to perform the recursion.  In this case, one extra argument is provided, an *accumulator* (the empty list), to store the results.

Once you know the accumulator trick, then writing a function to reverse a list is trivial.  After you've coded the reverse function a few times in your modules, you can use `Enum.reverse/1` in your code instead.

I suggest when starting out that you don't ever use `++`.  Pretend it doesn't exist.  Instead, add things to the front of a list with the cons operator,`|`, and reverse lists before returning them if the order is important.

Also, note that this:

```
def is_bigger_then_3(list_int, res) when length(list_int) == 0 do
```

can be written more succinctly as:

```
def is_bigger_then_3([], res) do
```

Likewise, this:

```
def is_bigger_then_3(list_int, res) when length(list_int) > 0 do
```

can be written more succinctly as:

```
def is_bigger_then_3([number|numbers], res) do
```

A one element list looks like this:

```
[1 | []]
```

so the head is `1` and the tail is the empty list `[]`.  In iex:

```
iex(5)> list = [1|[]]
[1]

iex(6)> [head|tail] = list
[1]

iex(7)> head
1

iex(8)> tail
[]
```

As a result, a list with one or more elements will match the function clause:

```
def is_bigger_then_3([number|numbers], res) do
```

and the empty list will match the function clause:

```
def is_bigger_then_3([], res) do
```

You also might wonder why your output includes things like this:

```
~c"\a\b\t"
```

In elixir, there are things called `charlists`, which are lists of integers.  If a list contains all integers which happen to be the ascii codes for "printable" characters (see an ascii chart), then iex will output the list of integers as a string.  In older versions of elixir, iex would output charlists as single quoted strings containing the ascii characters corresponding to the integers:

```
test_scores = [97,98,99]
'abc'
```

In newer versions of elixir, you would see:

```
~c"abc"
```

That is really inconvenient when you want to examine the test scores, and instead you see gibberish such as:

```
~c"abc"
```

You can configure iex, so that charlists, i.e. lists containing integers which all happen to be ascii codes for printable characters, are output as lists of integers instead of single quoted strings (or ~c strings):

```
iex(1)> test_scores = [97,98,99]
'abc'

iex(2)> IEx.configure(inspect:  [charlists: :aslists])
:ok

iex(3)> test_scores                     
[97, 98, 99]
```

You can even use a [configuration file](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.12.3/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file), so that iex always starts up with that configuration--which is a helpful thing to do.  The default iex configuration, which outputs some lists of integers as strings, can cause a lot of confusion.

In your case, the output was `~c"\a\b\t"`, and if you look at the [escape sequences allowed in a string](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/main/String.html#module-escape-characters), `\a` represents a Bell character, `\b` represents a Backspace character, and `\t` represents a Horizontal Tab character.  An ascii chart will reveal that those characters have the ascii codes 7, 8, 9, which is what you were trying to output, but iex converted the list of integers to a string.

Comment: “The lesson is: the recursive function call should be the last line of your function.”—this is plain wrong.

Comment: “I suggest when starting out that you don't ever use `++`.”—Eh. And how am I supposed to concatenate two lists of arbitrary length?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, Take a beginning erlang class.

Comment: Not to split hairs (well I guess we should split some hairs as software developers) but this is some rather tortured English and probably doesn't convey what you meant to convey: "_if statements and unless statements are expressions, which means they return values_"--probably better to have said "The if and unless macros are expressions which means they return values".  Saying they're statements and then two words later saying they're expressions seems unduly confusing to me.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, Saying they're macros and then two words later saying they're expressions seems unduly confusing to me.  This is some rather tortured English and probably doesn't convey what you meant to convey.

Comment: I can see that probably I didn't explain my concern very well.  The term _expression_ in my experience means something that's expected to return a value--whereas the term _statement_ generally means a construct that's run solely for side-effects.  In imperative languages (e. g. C#) some constructs (statements) do not return a value. `int x;` simply declares storage for a variable called `x`.  An expression always returns a value. `x++` returns the value of x incremented by one.  In Elixir and most other FP paradigm languages there are no "statements"--everything is an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Aleiksei's answer/comments here are on point.  I can only add a couple examples here that may be simpler representations of what you're trying to do.

Any time you need to covert a list of things into another list of things with the same number of elements (i.e. 1:1), [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) is your friend.

Consider this:

```
iex> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
iex> Enum.map(list, fn x -> x > 3 end)
[false, false, false, true]
```

If you need to convert a list of things into another list of things where the number of items is NOT 1:1, then use [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3), e.g.

```
iex> list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
iex> Enum.reduce(list, [], fn x, acc ->
  if x > 3 do
    [x | acc]
  else
    acc
  end
end)
[4]
```

Although that's the basic idea, for something as simple as filtering a list, it would be more straightforward to use `Enum.filter/2`:

```
iex> Enum.filter(list, fn x -> x > 3 end)
```

There's also an `Enum.reject/2` function that operates similarly.

As Aleksei and others noted, it is more performant to prepend to a list, so if you are rolling your own reduce operation, you may need to reverse the list (via `Enum.reverse/1`) as a final step.

The `Enum` module is one of the most important (perhaps THE most important?) module in Elixir.

If the `Enum` module doesn't quite do what you need (or you are exploring other patterns), then you may end up writing your own recursive functions.  Most often, these functions will feature multiple clauses where one of them is the final clause, usually matching on an empty list -- this has to be the first function clause.

E.g. here is an adaptation of the problem using ad-hoc tail-recursion.  Note: this is for demonstration only -- it's overkill to engineer a verbose custom solution like this when the built-in functions would do a better job and likely be more performant.

```
defmodule MyFuncs do
  @doc """
  Examples:

      iex> MyFuncs.bigger_than([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
      [4]

  """
  def bigger_than(list, x) when is_list(list), do: filter(list, x, [])

  defp filter([], _, acc), do: Enum.reverse(acc)

  defp filter([head | tail], n, acc) when head > n do
    filter(tail, n, [head | acc])
  end

  defp filter([_head | tail], n, acc) do
    filter(tail, n, acc)
  end
end
```